# tensorflow different computer same code different results

Tags: python, nan, tensorflow, cross-entropy

While using *tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits* in training process, the result frequently gives **nan** or **exceptionally big cross entropy values**.

(Windows 7 64bit
Python 3.6 (Anaconda 4.4.0)
Tensorflow 1.4
NVIDIA Titan X Pascal
CUDA 8.0
CUDNN 6.0.)

> Epoch00  CrossEntropy: 1.288   L2_loss: 1247.340   Cost: 32.489
>
> Epoch01  CrossEntropy: 0.936   L2_loss: 1019.474   Cost: 23.868
>
> Epoch02  CrossEntropy: 0.550   L2_loss: 880.814   Cost: 14.669
>
> Epoch03  CrossEntropy: 0.331   L2_loss: 796.639   Cost: 9.435
>
> Epoch04  CrossEntropy: nan   L2_loss: nan   Cost: nan
>
> Epoch05  CrossEntropy: nan   L2_loss: nan   Cost: nan

But this does not happen in another computer.
Exactly the same code, the same data.

(Windows 7 64bit
Python 3.6 (Anaconda 4.4.0)
Tensorflow 1.3
NVIDIA GeForce GTX TITAN X
CUDA 8.0
CUDNN 7.0)

> Epoch00  CrossEntropy: 1.277   L2_loss: 1247.637   Cost: 32.244
>
> Epoch01  CrossEntropy: 0.938   L2_loss: 1018.631   Cost: 23.917
>
> Epoch02  CrossEntropy: 0.575   L2_loss: 878.269   Cost: 15.250
>
> Epoch03  CrossEntropy: 0.345   L2_loss: 795.507   Cost: 9.766
>
> Epoch04  CrossEntropy: 0.240   L2_loss: 741.619   Cost: 7.226
>
> Epoch05  CrossEntropy: 0.193   L2_loss: 704.291   Cost: 6.051

I also tried in Linux Envinronment, but the results would give nan or big cross entropy values.
Does anyone have any idea on this problem?